# LinQ to XML; query descendants using parent node value

Tags: linq-to-xml, parent-child

Hi I have the following XML structure:

```
<Root>
 <Persons>
  <PersonList Category="Employee">
   <Person Name="John" Id="5" />
   <Person Name="Mary" Id="10" />
  </PersonList>
 </Persons>
</Root>
```

I am looking to use LinqtoXML and in order to get a list of available Person I can simply write this query:

```
var persons = from p in myDoc.Descendants("Person")
select p;
```

Now, what I have to do in order to get all the Person **where** the Category in PersonList Element is = to a specific value? I can't use **Parent** because I need to specify the **PersonList** element as the structure of the XML may be different than this one but not the element name.
Is it possible?

Comment: Your reason for not using Parent isn't clear at all. Could you give an example of why it might fail?

Comment: @Jon: It sounds like he's saying that the nesting may be different.

Comment: @SLaks: It's possible, but not clear... and not clear what he wants to do if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for

```
var people = myDoc.Descendants("PersonList")
                  .Where(p => p.Attribute("Category").Value == something)
                  .Descendants("Person");
```

If you want to get the category of a specific `<Person>` element, you can write

```
var category = elem.AncestorsAndSelf("PersonList")
                   .First().Attribute("Category").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks SLacks, this is what I was looking for.
For the other guys, the problem is that in the future I may have the Person element nested into 4 or 5 more parents so that the PersonList element may be the 5th parent element and not anymore the 3rd like now.